# Add control before another control

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am adding one control based on some condition

```
if(x = true)
    dv1.Controls.Add(lnkTest);
else
    dv2.Controls.Add(lnkTest);
```

As I am adding many controls so for the sake of readability I was checking this condition after adding all other controls. But it will add control `lnkTest` after all the controls as it is called after them. I have no problem in moving this code to proper location where I want but it will compromise readability a bit. I was just wondering if there is any way to add `lnkTest` before any control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AddAt method allows you to specify location index at which you want to insert the control. Use index 0 for the very beginning:

```
dv1.Controls.AddAt(0, lnkTest);
```

However note that this will insert `lnkTest` before any children, including those that you did not insert yourself. So you should, perhaps, remember the place where the insert should happen:

```
int start = dv1.Controls.Count();
// insert all other controls
dv1.Controls.AddAt(start, lnkTest);
```

And remember you need to do that for both `dv1` and `dv2`. At that point I would argue your `if` probably won't hurt readability more than this memorization.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `AddAt` method like this:

```
dv1.Controls.AddAt(0, lnkTest);
```

Reference: [ControlCollection.AddAt Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection.addat(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Adds the specified Control object to the collection at the specified index location.